# Land Change Modeler?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am doing an urban prediction using some classified image of previous years. It can be done through Land Change Modeler. It is an Arc-GIS extension tool. I have the license too. But the tool is not showing in my toolbox.

What should i do ?

Comment: Have you enabled it? Customize menu - Extensions, or perhaps Customize - Toolbars. You could also try Geoprocessing - Search For Tools

Comment: Yes Sir. My tools are activated. I can see all my tools. But Land Change modeler is an extension. https://www.geospatialworld.net/news/land-change-modeler-software-extension-for-arcgis/ . May be recently added or dont know much. But I need it.

Comment: What instructions are you following?  What precise steps have you performed?

Comment: I am following one concept called Markov Chain Cellular Automata which helps to predict the urban growth mode for future year. And this can be done by LanduseSim Land change modeler and IDRISI softwares and tools. So, from web source i could know that land change modeler is an extension to ArcGIS. And i have the license.